# How to format date correctly using Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, date-format, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using SpringBoot 2.2.5 with Elasticsearch 6.8.6. I'm in progress of migrating from Spring Data Jest to using the Spring Data Elasticsearch REST transport mechanism with `ElasticsearchEntityMapper`.

I have a `Date` field with the following definition:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private Date date;
```

I would like the date stored in Elasticsearch like this:

```
"date": "2020-04-02T14:49:05.672+0000"
```

When I start the application, the index is created but when I try to save the entity I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/trends/estrend?timeout=1m], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [date] of type [date] in document with id 'rS5UP3EB9eKtCTMXW_Ky'"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [date] of type [date] in document with id 'rS5UP3EB9eKtCTMXW_Ky'","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Invalid format: \"1585905425266\" is malformed at \"5266\""}},"status":400}
```

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong and what I should do to fix it?

Configuration and entity definitions below:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.host}")
    private String elasticSearchHost;

    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.port}")
    private String elasticSearchPort;

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
        .connectedTo(elasticSearchHost + ":" + elasticSearchPort)
        .usingSsl()
        .build();
        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityMapper entityMapper() {
        ElasticsearchEntityMapper entityMapper = new ElasticsearchEntityMapper(elasticsearchMappingContext(), new DefaultConversionService());
        entityMapper.setConversions(elasticsearchCustomConversions());
        return entityMapper;
    }
}


package com.es.test;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.DateFormat;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;

@Document(indexName = "trends")
public class EsTrend {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    private Date date;

    private String entityOrRelationshipId;

    // getter and setters

}
```

***Update***:

If I disable the `ElasticsearchEntityMapper` bean, I don't get the exception and the date is written in the correct format to Elasticsearch. Is there anything else I need to configure for the `ElasticsearchEntityMapper`?

Comment: How does your mapping for the date-field look like? Or do you use dynamic mapping, meaning you dont have set up an explicit mapping for the index  previously?

Comment: Using this site https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ the unix timestamp pointed out in the error message is converted to 52225-05-05T20:47:46+00:00 . So something is wrong with your input data.

Comment: I'm relying on dynamic mapping.

Comment: To test I'm using  `trend1.setDate(new Date());` Not sure why this is failing.

Comment: Can you try it again without the `@JsonFormat` annotation?

Comment: Removed `@JsonFormat`, same exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please don't use the Jackson based default mapper. It is removed in the next major version of Spring Data Elasticsearch (4.0). Then there will be no choice available, and internally the `ElasticsearchEntityMapper`is used.

As to your problem: The `ElasticsearchEntityMapper`in version 3.2, which is used by Spring Boot currently, does not use the date relevant information from the `@Field` attribute to convert the entity, it is only used for the index mappings creation. This was a missing feature or bug and is fixed in the next major version, the whole mapping process was overhauled there.

What you can do in your current situation: You need to add custom converters. You can do this in your configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.host}")
    private String elasticSearchHost;

    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.port}")
    private String elasticSearchPort;

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo(elasticSearchHost + ":" + elasticSearchPort)
            .usingSsl()
            .build();
        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityMapper entityMapper() {
        ElasticsearchEntityMapper entityMapper = new ElasticsearchEntityMapper(elasticsearchMappingContext(), new DefaultConversionService());
        entityMapper.setConversions(elasticsearchCustomConversions());
        return entityMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public ElasticsearchCustomConversions elasticsearchCustomConversions() {
        return new ElasticsearchCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(DateToStringConverter.INSTANCE, StringToDateConverter.INSTANCE));
    }

    @WritingConverter
    enum DateToStringConverter implements Converter<Date, String> {
        INSTANCE;
        @Override
        public String convert(Date date) {
            return formatter.format(date);
        }
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    enum StringToDateConverter implements Converter<String, Date> {
        INSTANCE;
        @Override
        public Date convert(String s) {
            try {
                return formatter.parse(s);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You still need to have the dateformat in the `@Field` anotation though, because it is needed to create the correct index mappings.

And you should change your code to use the Java 8 introduced time classes like `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`, Spring Data Elasticsearch supports these out of the box, whereas `java.util.Date` would need custom converters.

**Edit 09.04.2020:** added the necessary `@WritingConverter` and  `@ReadingConverter` annotations.

**Edit 19.04.2020:** Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0 will support the `java.util.Date` class out of the box with the `@Field` annotation as well.

Comment: Thanks P.J, really appreciate the support. I managed to get `Date` working with the customer convertors. I then tried to use `LocalDateTime` without the custom convertor and got the same exception. I must be doing something wrong. Would it be possible for you to post examples of how to use `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`? Maybe this should put into the current documentation as other developers may also face the same issues.

Comment: in 3.2.5 you would need CustomConverters as well, it's in Spring Data Elasticsearch, that the `java.time` classes work out of the box with just the `@Field'  annotation

Comment: OK thanks. Just got back to code today and tried to add some more String attributes to the entity with the date convertors enabled above. When saved to Elasticsearch, the string attributes are all set to null. Shouldn't the convertors only affect the date fields?

Comment: sure, that's why they have a source and target type. Do you have getters and setters for the new properties?

Comment: Yes. If i disable the convertors, the entity gets written correctly (bar the date). The Elasticsearch entity is created using model mapper from another entity (another datastore), I don't think that should cause a problem.

Comment: my fault. two annotations missing; see my updated answer.

Comment: Hurrah it worked! thanks P.J. Well worth a mention in the docs, I would never have had worked this out. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Hi, what if I dont need `RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient`, but still need converters? 
I have another configs in project for ES connection that are working correctly.
How could I have `ElasticsearchCustomConversions elasticsearchCustomConversions `?

Comment: @andrew17 hard to say without knowing how you configure Spring Data Elasticsearch

Comment: Its fine, I found that I can use `format = DateFormat.date_hour_minute_second` in my version

Answer (score 0):

As I am a new joiner,I can't comment under @P.J.Meisch's anwser by the stack rules.
I also faced the problem, and solved it with @P.J.Meisch's anwser.
But just a little change with the @ReadingConverter.
Infact, the raw type read from ES, is Long, and the result type in java we need is LocalDateTime. Thus, the read converter shoud be Long to LocalDateTime.
Code follows below:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchClientConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    public final static int TIME_OUT_MILLIS = 50000;

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchProperties elasticsearchProperties;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo(elasticsearchProperties.getHost() + ":" + elasticsearchProperties.getPort())
                .withBasicAuth(elasticsearchProperties.getName(), elasticsearchProperties.getPassword())
                .withSocketTimeout(TIME_OUT_MILLIS)
                .withConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT_MILLIS)
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    /**
     * Java LocalDateTime to ElasticSearch Date mapping
     *
     * @return EntityMapper
     */
    @Override
    @Bean
    public EntityMapper entityMapper() {
        ElasticsearchEntityMapper entityMapper = new ElasticsearchEntityMapper(elasticsearchMappingContext(), new DefaultConversionService());
        entityMapper.setConversions(elasticsearchCustomConversions());
        return entityMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public ElasticsearchCustomConversions elasticsearchCustomConversions() {
        return new ElasticsearchCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(DateToStringConverter.INSTANCE, LongToLocalDateTimeConverter.INSTANCE));
    }

    @WritingConverter
    enum DateToStringConverter implements Converter<Date, String> {
        /**
         * instance
         */
        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public String convert(@NonNull Date date) {
            return DateUtil.format(date, DateConstant.TIME_PATTERN);
        }
    }

    **@ReadingConverter
    enum LongToLocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Long, LocalDateTime> {
        /**
         * instance
         */
        INSTANCE;
        @Override
        public LocalDateTime convert(@NonNull Long s) {
            return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(s), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }
    }**

}
```

and the DateUtil file:

```
public class DateUtil {
    /**
     * lock obj
     */
    private static final Object LOCK_OBJ = new Object();

    /**
     * sdf Map for different pattern
     */
    private static final Map<String, ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>> LOCAL_MAP = new HashMap<>();


    /**
     * thread safe
     *
     * @param pattern pattern
     * @return SimpleDateFormat
     */
    private static SimpleDateFormat getSdf(final String pattern) {
        ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> tl = LOCAL_MAP.get(pattern);

        if (tl == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK_OBJ) {
                tl = LOCAL_MAP.get(pattern);
                if (tl == null) {
                    System.out.println("put new sdf of pattern " + pattern + " to map");
                    tl = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
                        System.out.println("thread: " + Thread.currentThread() + " init pattern: " + pattern);
                        return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
                    });
                    LOCAL_MAP.put(pattern, tl);
                }
            }
        }

        return tl.get();
    }

    /**
     * format
     *
     * @param date    date
     * @param pattern pattern
     * @return String
     */
    public static String format(Date date, String pattern) {
        return getSdf(pattern).format(date);
    }

}
```

at last,

pls vote for @P.J.Meisch, not me.