# MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity while implementing AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to implement custom converter for my object following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008881/how-to-format-date-correctly-using-spring-data-elasticsearch) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008881/how-to-format-date-correctly-using-spring-data-elasticsearch) answer, but when I ran the project I received MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class TransactionElastic

Here is my config

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {


    @Value("$elasticUrl")
    private String elasticUrl;

    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        return RestClients.create(ClientConfiguration.create(elasticUrl)).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityMapper entityMapper() {
        ElasticsearchEntityMapper entityMapper = new ElasticsearchEntityMapper(elasticsearchMappingContext(), new DefaultConversionService());
        entityMapper.setConversions(elasticsearchCustomConversions());
        return entityMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public ElasticsearchCustomConversions elasticsearchCustomConversions() {
        return new ElasticsearchCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(new TransactionToMapConverter(), new MapToTransactionConverter()));
    }
}

@WritingConverter
public class TransactionToMapConverter implements Converter<TransactionElastic, Map<String, Object>> {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> convert(TransactionElastic tradeTransaction) {
        Map<String, Object> target = new HashMap<>();
        target.put("id", tradeTransaction.getId());
        target.put("portfolio_name", tradeTransaction.getPortfolioName());
        target.put("settl_date", tradeTransaction.getSettlDate());
        return target;
    }
}
@ReadingConverter
public class MapToTransactionConverter implements Converter<Map<String, Object>, TransactionElastic> {
    @Override
    public TransactionElastic convert(Map<String, Object> map) {
        TransactionElastic t = new TransactionElastic();
        t.setPortfolioName(map.get("portfolio_name").toString());
        t.setId((Long) map.get("id"));
        return t;
    }
}

@Document(indexName = "transactions")
public class TransactionElastic {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Field(name = "portfolio_name", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String portfolioName;
    @Field(name = "settl_date", type = FieldType.Date)
    private Date settlDate;
    @Field(name = "trscn_status", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String trscnStatus;
    // getters and setters here 
}
```

Stacktrace

```
15:49:41.488 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'techNeedsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'elasticService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionServiceElastic': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'transactionElasticRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionElasticRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.portal.domain.TransactionElastic!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.portal.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionServiceElastic': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'transactionElasticRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionElasticRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.portal.domain.TransactionElastic!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionElasticRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.portal.domain.TransactionElastic!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.portal.domain.TransactionElastic!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchEntityInformationCreatorImpl.getEntityInformation(ElasticsearchEntityInformationCreatorImpl.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Registering convertors logs

```
o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions - Registering converter from class com.portal.domain.TransactionElastic to interface java.util.Map as writing converter although it doesn't convert to a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions - Registering converter from interface java.util.Map to class com.portal.domain.TransactionElastic as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions - Registering converter from class org.springframework.data.geo.Point to interface java.util.Map as writing converter although it doesn't convert to a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions - Registering converter from interface java.util.Map to class org.springframework.data.geo.Point as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions - Registering converter from class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint to interface java.util.Map as writing converter although it doesn't convert to a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions - Registering converter from interface java.util.Map to class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
```

Spring boot version 2.2.1
Spring data elasticsearch 3.2.1
Elasticsearch version 6.4.0

What might cause the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: Hi @SimonMartinelli, I have updated the question, added stacktrace

Comment: How does your package structure look like?

Comment: com.portal.domain - for @Document objects 
com.portal.search - elasticsearch repositories
com.portal.service - for service interfaces and implementation
com.portal.config - with configs
com.portal.converter - with converters

Comment: And in which package is SpringBootApplication?

Comment: Actually it is in a separate module. We have splitted application, common part extracted to the core module. Core module added as maven dependency, not java 9 module, on the project used java 8. Works fine with JPA, that is why not mentioned  before

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's not able to find entities. Please extends the following method in `AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration`:

```
@Override
protected Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages() {
    //Provide list of your packages where you have entities.
}
```

Comment: Updated my config as follow
 @Override
    protected Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages() {
        return Collections.singletonList("com.meritkapital.portal.domain");
    } 
but still have same exception

Comment: What I also recommend is to try to create a simple configuration bean instead of extending the AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration, because it's disabling some auto-configurations. Instead of extending that, just create a configuration bean and create method level beans for what you need.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Tried to leave only Elasticsearch CustomConversions method bean in config but doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

## Spring Boot Devtools

Are you using Spring Boot Devtools?  DevTools can cause the MappingException error you are seeing because of its use of multiple classloaders.

One fix is to exclude your mapping package using the `spring.devtools.additional-exclude` property in your application.properties or application.yml like this:

```
spring.devtools.additional-exclude: static/**,com.portal.domain/**
```

A more drastic approach is to stop using devtools, but doing this will disable the LiveReload capability which is nice to have during development:

In Maven's pom.xml:

```xml
<!-- <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
 <optional>true</optional>
</dependency> -->
```

In Gradle's build.gradle:

```
/* compileOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools") */
```

Devtools is only used in development and should not be disabled by default in production code.  So if this is the error, your code should work when deployed in production.

## The Cause

The cause of the error appears to be in this snippet of code in DefaultReactiveIndexOperations:

```java
    private IndexCoordinates getIndexCoordinatesFor(Class<?> clazz) {
        return operations.getElasticsearchConverter().getMappingContext().getRequiredPersistentEntity(clazz)
                .getIndexCoordinates();
    }
```

The call to `getRequiredPersisentEntity(clazz)` fails because it looks up `clazz` in a map of class -> PersistentEntities, and the class is different because of the separate class loader.

I do not know why the mapping class is loaded in separate class loaders.